# Why is parasitic capacitance in inductor said to be in parallel?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, capacitance, inductance

Internal resistance of inductance (or other devices) are said to be in series. But [parasitic capacitance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parasitic_capacitance) is said to be in parallel (in case of an inductor). Why is that so? What determines whether an internal property is in series or parallel?

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 4):

From a circuit theory perspective, an inductor is effectively a short-circuit (wire) at DC while a capacitor is an open-circuit.

Thus, any parasitic capacitance *must* be in parallel since, if it were in series, an inductor would be an open-circuit at DC.

From an AC perspective, if the parasitic capacitance were in series, the inductor would appear *capacitive* at low frequencies and *inductive* at frequencies above the self-resonance frequency:

$$Z = j \omega L + \frac{1}{j \omega C} = \frac{1}{j\omega C} \left( 1 - \omega^2LC\right)$$

But, in fact, we see the opposite, the physical inductor is inductive at low frequencies and appears capacitive at frequencies above the self-resonance frequency.

$$Z = j\omega L || \frac{1}{j\omega C} = j \omega L\left(\frac{1}{1 - \omega^2LC}\right) $$

Comment: Will it hold good in AC too? My friend is working in RF generator and told me about the parasitic capacitance. And AC is used in RF generation.

Comment: @karthikeyan, see update.

Comment: Beautiful answer, Thank you !